# String / Date replacement based on if condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to replace the missing months with the month that is missed

I have a data from which I am creating arrays DATE, MARKETS. In the data, there are few months that are missing. I have written the below code to replace the missed month. For that I have written the below code
Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ah4c0oah/4/)

```
var data = [
{ "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-SEP-14|0.59" },
{ "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-MAY-14|0.87" },
{ "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-NOV-14|0.25" },
{ "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-JUL-14|0.67" },
{ "MFG_NAME": "ABC", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.10" },
{ "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-OCT-14|0.03" },
{ "MFG_NAME": "XYZ", "CONCATED_MKT_SHARE": "01-DEC-14|0.14" }];
var monthNames = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var ctdate = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;// getting current month
var dynmonths = new Array();
dynmonths = monthNames.slice(ctdate).concat(monthNames.slice(0, ctdate));//creating array of months starting from current month
var DATES = [[], []];
var MARKETS = [[], []];
var mfg;
function findDataForMonth(mfgName, month) {
  for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
    var datum = data[i];
    if (datum.MFG_NAME === mfgName && datum.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.indexOf(month) >= 0) {
        return datum.CONCATED_MKT_SHARE.split('|')[1];
      }
     }
   }

for (var i = 0, length = dynmonths.length; i < length; i++) {
// what is the if condition that has to be written here  
var month = '01-' + dynmonths[i] + '-14';
alert(month);   //the output here is 01-APR-14, 01-MAY-14, 01-JUN-14, 01-JUL-14, 01-AUG-14, 01-SEP-14, 01-OCT-14, 01-NOV-14, 01-DEC-14, `01-JAN-14, 01-FEB-14, 01-MAR-14`

 //Here after 01-DEC-14 the next must be 01-JAN-15 instead it is 01-JAN-14.  How do I get it?

MARKETS[0].push(findDataForMonth("ABC", month) || 0.0);
MARKETS[1].push(findDataForMonth("XYZ", month) || 0.0);

DATES[0].push(month);
DATES[1].push(month);
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You said "I am trying to replace the missing months with the month that is missed" and then later you said "I have written the below code to replace the missed month.". So what is your question?

Comment: @Moogs - question is the comments in the code itself.  OP seemingly does not know how to handle a new year.

Comment: Will you always have months of **the same** year in your `data` array?

Comment: No not the same year. It considers the current month. Based upon the current month the previous 12 months are obtained using the above code and after that the dates are looped starting from currentmonth-12 to the current month

Comment: @Moogs Did you understand my question?